# Mixing UTF-8 with UTF-16

Tags: encoding, utf-8

I'm currently working on a korean program, which should be translated into chinese language. What I found strange, is that application is mixing UTF-8 and UTF-16 characters.

Let's say we've a string which goes as:

```
"게임을 정말로 종료하시겠습니까"
8C AC 84 C7 44 C7 20 00 15 C8 D0 B9 5C B8 20 00
85 C8 CC B8 58 D5 DC C2 A0 AC B5 C2 C8 B2 4C AE 00
```

But it's stored as

```
B0 D4 C0 D3 C0 BB 20 C1 A4 B8 BB B7 CE 20 C1 BE
B7 E1 C7 CF BD C3 B0 DA BD C0 B4 CF B1 EE 3F 00
```

just to prevent zeros. I'd like to know, if it's some kind of encryption, or is it just a normal method used by compilers to prevent end of the string somewhere in the middle of the string? Because, the final result is the first string, that I've mentioned. Any reading would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: See http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: It uses an olden multibyte encoding, the byte values are a match for [code page 949](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_949).

Comment: @HansPassant Are you able to give me further tips, on turning this encoding into normal UTF-16 string?

Comment: you didn't say which operating system you are running on or what programming language you are using, so all we can tell you is that this is code page 949, and you can convert it to utf16 using whatever methods are available on your platform nd in your language.

Comment: Thank you very much, mr. @HansPassant. I've found out this code: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/fatfs/src/option/cc949.c.inc which does everything I need. :)

Answer (score 1):

A string must be either uft-8 or utf-16 (or some other encoding). If you mix encodings in a string it is an error. However it is very common to pass string about as utf-8, and only convert them to utf-16 when needed by a Windows function. There are several reasons for this, Basile Starynkevitch has provided a link.

If you need routines to read UFT-8, I've got some here.

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyx/blob/master/src/common/BBX_Font.c

Comment: Strings are UTF-8, but UTF-16 characters, have been converted to UTF-8 (no zeros). This is where my question actually starts. As example, I'll give a few examples: (54448) B0 D4 -> (44172) [게] 8C AC | (54704) B0 D5 -> (44176) [겐] 90 AC | (54960) B0 D6 -> (44180) [겔] 94 AC. I'm not sure if it's some kind of encryption, or it's just encoding thing.

Comment: @mexicanoZ not sure why you're saying UTF-8 has no zeros. UTF 8 encodes 00 as 00. It does not eliminate zeros. It preserves them.

Comment: UTF-8 has no zero bytes within the string. Except the nul byte which is also codepoint 0 and, in the C family of languages, end of string.